# C# TCP/IP socket programming

Tags: multithreading, sockets, thread-safety, c#-3.0

I am connecting to a server program using TCP/IP synchronous socket from multiple client programs.

There,I am making multiple requests to the server at the same time and get the response(via multiple threads).

Every time when I am making a request to server program , the .net the framework automatically assigned a port to each client & it will get the correct response.

My questions is , I've an assumption. since each client has  a different port (endpoints) even though the requests are firing at the same time to same server , the response will receive and redirected to the correct caller(client). 
But sometimes I have seen , the responses are mixing & it reaches to the wrong client program.
If i put a lock on that socket creation and receiving code then it is getting the correct responses.

Also Please note that I've created program in a thread safe manner.

Kindly explain me where the issue is and Is my assumption is correct or not.

Thanks.

Comment: without our server code it's hard to suggest something.... You can post here code that you are using on server side for sending data. Maybe not all of them, but some main parts

Comment: Your code has a bug. Neither TCP nor the OS can ever mix things up. Since the code is missing nobody can possibly provide an answer. Closing. @SergeyLitvinov you should have voted to close as well. This is a clear case.

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov Is my assumption mention ABOVE CORRECT?

Comment: @usr Please forget abt the bug in the code . Could you please tell me the approach ,the concept or the assumption made by me are correct. Thanks.

Comment: What *is* your assumption? Is it that data can be mixed up? Then no, that is never the case. That would make it impossible to write a functioning program.

Comment: If only lock gives the correct response then **your code was not thread-safe**. Why are you claiming it is 100% thread-safe?

Comment: Your approach makes no sense. You agree that the OS does not garble data. That means **your code garbles data. And it's not here to see.**